# Applying machine learning inside an IDE

Tags: java, machine-learning

I am trying to understand machine learning and its practical usages. My preliminary understanding is that machine learning is used mostly in data science these days and it can also be used to solve classification, nlp, pattern recognition, and other problems.

I have a specific scenario to which I want to apply  machine learning principles/algorithms. I want to apply it inside an IDE and see what the developer is up to from code change perspective. So instead of what a version control system would do - identify textual changes in your code, I want to build a system that can make sense of code changes with in a file (may be by **"categorizing"/"classifying"** changes at an abstract syntax tree level), match known patterns, trigger actions based on matched patterns or leave it up the code to **discover** new patterns.

Am I trying to solve something really simple which doesn't even qualify as a machine learning problem statement? Are there simple methods out there to solve this kind of a scenario?

p.s: added a java tag, because this is for a java based product - so I am hoping that there would be relevant suggestions in this area w.r.t what libraries/algorithms to use.

Comment: Cool, but what's your question?

Comment: updated questions. if that answers your question, consider removing the downvote.

Comment: Still, I find your question unclear/unfit for the SO format. With all due respect, I think that other stack exchange boards (programmers, data science) may be better suited to ask this question.

Comment: @okiharaherbst machine-learning on this site has been tagged 5000 times. Most of the questions have no code in them. So, I don't see why it won't fit. What I do notice as a 5 year member on this site, with all due respect, is that, these days there are too many people on this forum who are eager to downvote questions - and everytime I ask a question I end up writing a justification like this. And, I've asked close to 120 questions.

Comment: Life is unfair. SO is no different.

Comment: Last place I expected a philosophical answer from :-)